# I want to optimize SQL query where different columns of same table are compared with columns of another table in or condition

Tags: sql, subquery, query-optimization

I have 2 tables (t1 , t2) with columns A1, A2, A3. I want to write a SQL query which returns the rows in table t1, for which A1 column value is same as table t2 but the A2 or A3 or both column value is different.

This query does the job, but does not seem to be optimized:

```
select t1.A1, t1.A2, t1.A3 
from t1 
where t1.A3 not In (select A3 from t2 where t2.A1 = t1.A1) 
   or t1.A2 not In (select A2 from t2 where t2.A1 = t1.A1);
```

Comment: Try with an EXISTS

Comment: You want something in t1 that exists in t2. But ok, don't try and keep this one.

Comment: Hi - can you clarify what you mean by "does not seem to be optimized" - surely it either is or it isn't? What's your definition of "optimized" in this scenario? Assuming you mean it's not running as quickly as you expected, please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN output for your query (the most detailed version your DBMS generates)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```sql
select *
from t1
where exists (
  select 1 
  from t2 
  where t2.a1 = t1.a1 and (t2.a2 <> t1.a2 or t2.a3 <> t1.a3)
)
```

To improve the query performance you can add the index:

```sql
create index ix1 on t2 (a1, a2, a3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, better than your's, but not equivalent to EXISTS:

```
select t1.A1, t1.A2, t1.A3 
from t1 
where (t1.A2, t1.A3) not In (select t2.A2, t2.A3 from t2 where t2.A1 = t1.A1);
```